# How to get poll()'s POLLHUP equivalent with select()?

Tags: c++, c, windows, mingw

I'm currently porting some code from Linux to Windows (with MinGW).

From what I [understand](http://mingw.5.n7.nabble.com/sys-poll-h-td7693.html), MinGW doesn't support `poll()`, which was used in the original, so I'm rewriting everything for `select()`.

And now I stumbled upon `if (pfd[i].revents & (POLLERR|POLLHUP))`...

How can I get the equivalent of this condition with `select()` - or alternatively, with whatever the winsock api or MinGW provides? The `POLLERR` part is simple enough; `if(FD_ISSET (i, &error_fd_set))` but I'm at loss about the `POLLHUP` part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. You have to use the "normal" way to find out whether the connection has been closed, that is reading from it.
In terms of code it'd be:

```
int rc = select(max_fd + 1, read_set, ..., ..., ...);
// check rc
for (int i = 0; i <= max_fd; ++i) {
  if (FD_ISSET(i, &read_set)) { // data incoming on i
     int rc = read(i, ..., ...); // or recv, if you use some flag
     if (rc == 0) {
        // i hung up
    }
  }
}
```

Otherwise, you can use `WSAPoll` which offers an API like the one you'd expect in UNIX-like systems.

Further information on [`WSAPoll`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wndp/archive/2006/10/26/wsapoll.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

According to my copy of [The Linux Programming Interface](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593272200), kernel poll events are mapped to `select()` events like so:

```
// Ready for reading
#define POLLIN_SET (POLLRDNORM | POLLRDBAND | POLLIN | POLLHUP | POLLERR)
// Ready for writing
#define POLLOUT_SET (POLLWRBAND | POLLWRNORM | POLLOUT | POLLERR)
// Exceptional condition
#define POLLEX_SET (POLLPRI)
```

So this suggests that you need to check the 'ready' event. To actually distinguish between POLLHUP, POLLIN, and POLLIN | POLLHUP, you can use the following chart from the book:

```
| ----- Condition or event ---- |
Data in pipe? | Write end open? | select() | poll()
no              no                r        | POLLHUP
yes             yes               r        | POLLIN
yes             no                r        | POLLIN | POLLHUP
```